# SSL Certification for Replicated Server

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

Really hope this hasn't been asked before, but here goes.

I am installing and configuring a server to use as a webhost for all their projects. I am also installing and configuring an additional identical server for redundancy (replicated via rsync and mysql replication). What I'd like to know is, can I configure the same SSL EV certificate on both servers or do I need separate ones for each server?

It's a basic LAMP server if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use the same certificate on all hosts which need it.

Comment: Thanks! Just needed an thumbs up!